# How can I insert multiple lines below a given line in sed with the line containing slashes

Tags: linux, bash, sed, scripting

I'm trying to insert the following lines below a line in my file:

```
<Test>
  <Document>
    ThisIsATest
  <Document>
</Test>
```

The line I want to insert these below is `This is a test.`

I can insert regular text just fine under it with the command `sed -i '/test/aThis is new text' test2.txt`, and the file will contain:

```
This is a test
This is new text
```

The difficult part is that I can't seem to do it with a multi-line item with slashes. Any ideas on how to do this? I don't have to use sed or awk; any other Linux utility would be fine as well.

Comment: The patterns you use with `sed` are "normally" delimited with slashes, like `s/this/that/g` but you can use a different character as the delimiter; `s~this~that~g` does the same thing. This is useful when the text you're searching or substituting contains slashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make use of sed's `r`  -> `read a file`

You save your multiple lines replacement text in a file, for example, `xml.txt`, you just do:

```
sed -i '/test/r xml.txt' file
```

You will get what you want.

Comment: If you prefer to not use a real file, you can create an anonymous one using the solution [here](http://tpcg.io/jJor3f).